# Download specific file from directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a folder that contains a bunch of csv files and I want to allow the user to download whichever one they need. The only catch is that new files are created on a daily basis so I can't just hardcode in the filenames.  Im wondering if its possible to pass in a parameter somehow from the views to the controller to allow the file requested to be downloaded but nothing I do seems to work...

Controller:

```
def download_file(file_to_download)
  send_file RAILS_ROOT + "/public/csv/" + file_to_download,
    :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
    :disposition => "attachment; filename=#{file_to_download}",
    :stream => true,
    :buffer_size => 4096
end
```

Views: (using haml)

```
%h1 Database Export
%h2 Date: #{Date.today}
%table
  %tr
    %td Click on a file to download
    - @files = Dir.glob("public/csv/*.csv")
    - for file in @files
      - name = File.basename(file, '.csv')
      %tr
        %td= link_to name, :controller => "csv_exports", :action => "download_file", :file_to_download => name + ".csv"
```

I get the error: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

However, my request params seem to be passing in what I want to use: {"file_to_download"=>"property_site_views_07-12-2012.csv"}

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rails controller methods are not supposed to take parameters.

you need to access your request parameter through the params option:

```
def download_file
  file_to_download = params[:file_to_download]
  send_file RAILS_ROOT + "/public/csv/" + file_to_download,
    :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
    :disposition => "attachment; filename=#{file_to_download}",
    :stream => true,
    :buffer_size => 4096
end
```

however passing through a user submitted value like this is considered a bad practice as it allowes injection. you should validate if the submitted filename is actually one that is in your list of files in that specific directory.

have a look at the guides for more infos on controllers: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html